# XamlReader.Parse and RadioButton GroupName

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button, xamlreader

I have very strange problem. Is there any possibility to have these two controls `radio` and `newRadio` have property `IsChecked == true`. Before code in line 6 is executed `radio.IsChecked == true`, but after executing code in line 6 `radio.IsChecked == false` and `newRadio.IsChecked == true`.

Is there any possibility that these two radio buttons will have `IsChecked == true` with the same `GroupName`?

```
1. RadioButton radio = new RadioButton();       

2. radio.GroupName = "group";
3. radio.IsChecked = true;          
4. radio.Name = "name";         

5. string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(radio);

6. var newRadio = XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname.aspx) -> "Gets or sets the name that specifies which RadioButton controls are mutually exclusive."

So usually no, if multiple radio buttons share the same group code only one should be checked at a time.

As a hack you could change the group name for the first radio button, create the second, and then put it back. You should get both radio buttons checked, but this is not something I would recommend.

Example:

```
radio.GroupName = String.Empty;
var newRadio = XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
radio.GroupName = "group";
```